# Is there a better way to suppress the ESLint error about the "triple-slash directive" at the top of Cypress jest tests?

Tags: eslint, cypress

The sample cypress jest spec tests have a "triple-slash directive" at the top of them which ESLint is reporting errors about.

It looks like this at the top of the [`actions.spec.js` file](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js):

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
```

ESLint is reporting this error:

> Expected exception block, space or tab after '//' in comment. [spaced-comment]

I have added `eslint-plugin-cypress` to my `.eslintrc` file and it helped to remove some other ESLint error (so I know it's installed/configured correctly), but it seems like this error should not have to be suppressed directly.

I have added the following [spaced-comment](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/spaced-comment) rule to my `.eslintrc` file which suppresses the error:

```js
{
  ...,

  "rules": {
    "spaced-comment": [
      "error",
      "always",
      {
        "markers": ["/"]
      }
    ]
  }

  ...,
}
```

Is there a better way to suppress this error?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I just installed Cypress and am annoyed with this error, but also don't want to disable it globally, because it is a style quirk that annoys me.

Comment: @paulwithap - I haven’t found a better solution yet. 

Comment: @BeauSmith, here is the solution you were seeking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473278/is-there-a-better-way-to-suppress-the-eslint-error-about-the-triple-slash-direc/75522198#75522198

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below line before the error line to suppress error

/*eslint spaced-comment: ["error", "never", { "block": { "balanced": true } }]*/

Comment: Thanks. Issue with this is that the pattern exists in many files. I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require editing each file this occurs in.

Comment: I do think that would make the triple-slash directives invalid because they have to be first thing in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I added the spaced-comment rule with a line marker exception. This worked for me:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "spaced-comment": [
      "error",
      "always",
      {
        "line": {
          "markers": ["/"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is in the original question. 

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress this error by adding a comment before the desired line:

```xml
    // eslint-disable-next-line spaced-comment
    /// <reference types="cypress" />
```

Or alternatively wrap it in the following way:

```xml
    // eslint-disable spaced-comment
    /// <reference types="cypress" />
    // eslint-enable spaced-comment
```